# Transfering site and domain ownership

Tags: ownership

I currently have a website through Google's blogspot and a couple of years ago I purchased and maintain up to today a custom domain name. I am about to transfer the ownership of the site to someone else. Through blogspot I can add that person as an administrator and then he will remove my access on the site. Now the issue is with the domain, whois etc. If it matters the domain name was purchased through GoDaddy. How can I transfer the domain name and change the whois details?

Comment: It has been a while, but this is generally fairly simple. The person you are transferring the domain to has to set up an account fully. They do not have to buy anything, just set it up. There is in the help pages and the GUI a way that you can transfer the site to your friends account simply. This goes smoothly. It is a lot harder to transfer to another registrar sometimes. I suggest doing this first even if you intend to use another registrar. It will make things easier in the end. Once you have transferred the domain, your friend can chose another registrar and make that change simply.

Comment: Registrar meaning alternative to GoDaddy? By the way I purchased the domain thourgh blogspot interface from godaddy. If that has any meaning. I do not have any login details or account details in GoDaddy

Comment: Okay. Not sure which way to go. I just know using GoDaddy that it is extremely easy to transfer a domain from one GoDaddy user to the next. It is also more difficult to transfer from one registrar to another but can be done okay. When I was a webhost, I used GoDaddy and the only headache I had was transferring to another registrar- it was not GoDaddy that was the problem. Some never got transferred. Again, not a GoDaddy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, transferring ownership/control of the website can be done as you mentioned, by assigning the other person administrator rights, and either removing your own admin rights, or having them remove them for you.

When it comes to transferring a domain, even between registrars, the process is actually pretty straight-forward.

All the other person needs to begin the process is an EPP/Auth code for your domain. You also need to "unlock" the domain to allow it to be transferred to someone else. Domains are generally "locked" to prevent unauthorized transfers, to keep your domain secure.

Getting the EPP code, and unlocking your domain, should be fairly easy.

You mentioned that you purchased the domain directly through Blogger. Here's a Google Help article with the steps to get your EPP code: https://support.google.com/a/answer/112049?hl=en

If you see an option to "Unlock" your domain while getting the EPP code, you should unlock the domain as well, or the transfer will fail.

Follow these steps, and when you receive the EPP code, provide it to the new site owner. They can use it at their registrar-of-choice to begin the transfer process.